# Datacursor not showing datetime on hover in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have `df` data:

```
                                        doc_count
@timestamp                                       
2017-07-28                                 110884
```

when I show them on graph:

```
ax = dfAll.plot(kind = kind, figsize = (16, 8), ax=ax)
datacursor(hover=True)
```

and hover into graph value I can see x= number and not date which I expect.

When I try this:

```
ax = plt.plot(dfAll.index, dfAll['doc_count'])
```

I can see date on my xaxis but I dont know how I can customized graph (kind and figsize)

Answer (score 0):

The matplotlib equivalent to the pandas wrapper

```
ax = dfAll.plot(kind = kind, figsize = (16, 8))
```

would depend on what `kind` is.
For `kind = "line"`,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16, 8))
line, = plt.plot(dfAll.index, dfAll['doc_count'])
```

For `kind = "bar"`,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16, 8))
bars = plt.bar(dfAll.index, dfAll['doc_count'])
```

etc.